# Elements are not showing up in the wrapper, they're below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a wrapper div set with a background color of white but all of my elements are showing up underneath the wrapper even though I have them set inside of it. I think it may have to do with the css of the slider I'm using but I'm not sure what to look for.

```css
/*MY CSS*/
#content-wrapper {
 padding-top: 4em;
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #fff;
}
#left-block {
 width: 49%;
}
#right-block {
 float: right;
 width: 45%;
}
#block-one, #block-two {
 width: 100%;
 height: 12em;
 background-color: black;
 vertical-align: top;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*SLIDER CSS*/
.bx-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 0 60px;
 padding: 0;
 *zoom: 1;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 border:  5px solid #fff;
 left: -5px;
 background: #fff;
 
 /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
 -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
 -moz-transform: translatez(0);
     -ms-transform: translatez(0);
     -o-transform: translatez(0);
     transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -30px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
 <div id="left-block">
  <ul class="bxslider">
     <li><img src="../images/slider/test-slide-1.svg" /></li>
     <li><img src="../images/slider/test-slide-2.svg" /></li>
     <li><img src="../images/slider/test-slide-3.svg" /></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="right-block">
  <div id="block-one"></div>
  <div id="block-two"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is related to how floating works. The right block should be placed before the first block (in HTML code). Also your wrapper in fact does not wrap the all the blocks, it just wraps the first block. while the second block has some part outside the wrapper. You can set `overflow:auto` for the wrapper to make it wrap all the blocks. (try adding some different distinct background or some border for the wrapper to see the problem).

Comment: Thank you for that, I don't know if that's a temporary solution or if that fixes it all but it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `float: left;` property for `#left-block` inside the CSS.

```css
/*MY CSS*/
#content-wrapper {
 padding-top: 4em;
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #fff;
}
#left-block {
 width: 49%;
    float: left;
}
#right-block {
 float: right;
 width: 45%;
}
#block-one, #block-two {
 width: 100%;
 height: 12em;
 background-color: black;
 vertical-align: top;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*SLIDER CSS*/
.bx-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 0 60px;
 padding: 0;
 *zoom: 1;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 border:  5px solid #fff;
 left: -5px;
 background: #fff;
 
 /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
 -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
 -moz-transform: translatez(0);
     -ms-transform: translatez(0);
     -o-transform: translatez(0);
     transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -30px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
 <div id="left-block">
  <ul class="bxslider">
     <li><img src="../images/slider/test-slide-1.svg" /></li>
     <li><img src="../images/slider/test-slide-2.svg" /></li>
     <li><img src="../images/slider/test-slide-3.svg" /></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="right-block">
  <div id="block-one"></div>
  <div id="block-two"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't affect anything on the page, all of the elements are still outside of the wrapper. Thank you though.

Comment: Are you using some other CSS as well other than the one which you've specified above? Because if you run the code snippet above, you can see that both the slider and the two black blocks are appearing inline.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I'm using other plugins with their own css which seems to lead to problems but I tried the overflow solution as the person above pointed out and it works.

Comment: Use a clearfix instead of an overflow hidden. http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/  and here is an example of some modular code that might help you. Stay away from those ID's.  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/qtmhoh3o/   Good luck.